# What are the generators of $\text{U}(3)$?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

How can I find the (nine) generators of $\text{U}(3)$?

I have started out by considering $\text{SU}(3)$, which is an 8-dimensional subgroup of $\text{U}(3)$. The generators of $\text{SU}(3)$ that are often used by particle physicists are the Gell-Mann matrices $\lambda^a$ (for $a = 1,2,\ldots,8$), given by:
\begin{alignat*}{4}
\lambda^1 &= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right) \,, \quad &\lambda^2 &= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -i & 0 \\
i & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right) \,, \quad &\lambda^3 &= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right) \\
\lambda^4 &= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right) \,, \quad &\lambda^5 &= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & -i \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
i & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right) \,, \quad &\lambda^6 &= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{array} \right) \\
\lambda^7 &= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -i \\
0 & i & 0
\end{array} \right) \,, \quad &\lambda^8 &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2
\end{array} \right) \,,
\end{alignat*}
and satisfying the commutation relation
\begin{equation*}
[\lambda^a,\lambda^b] = 2 i f^{abc} \lambda^c \,,
\end{equation*}
where $f^{abc}$ are the completely antisymmetric structure constants of $\text{SU}(3)$. Each element of $\text{SU}(3)$ can be written as $\exp (i \theta^j \lambda^j/2)$, where $\theta^j$ are real numbers and a sum over the index $j$ is implied. Furthermore, the Gell-Mann matrices are traceless, Hermitian, and obey the relation $\text{Tr}(\lambda^i \lambda^j) = 2\delta^{ij}$.

As the Gell-Mann matrices have nice properties, I would like to extend this set to obtain a full set of generators for $\text{U}(3)$. But how can I find this 'ninth' generator?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think by $U(3)$ you mean the Lie algebra of $U(3)$... notice your matrices are not even invertible! And what is the "dimension of the group", dimension as a manifold? These physicists....

Comment: As a physicist I apologize for any bad terminology from my side. You are right about these matrices not being invertible. The elements of $\text{SU}(3)$ can be written as $\exp(iθ^jλ^j/2)$ though, and these are perfectly invertible (as it should of course). And with the 'dimension' I mean the number of generators of the Lie group.

Answer (score 6):

You mean "infinitessimal generator," i.e. generator of the corresponding Lie algebras.  Anyhow, the unitary group $U(n)$ is generated as a group by $SU(n)$ and $U(1)\subset U(n)$, which is the subset of diagonal matrices with $e^{i\theta}$ in the top left corner and 1's elsewhere.  By differentiating, your ninth generator is probably the matrix with an $i$ in the top left corner and zeroes elsewhere.

For a quick reference, look at the first few paragraphs of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_group.

Edit: I don't have enough reputation to comment, but the number of generators of the $U(n)$ is infinite.  In fact this is already true for the circle $U(1)$ (any finite collection of elements generates a countable subset under the group laws).  In the interest of using the language correctly, you are looking at a basis for the Lie algebra.  The dimension means dimension as a real manifold, which is also the dimension of the lie algebra as a real vector space (even though its a real subspace of complex matrices).

Comment: Thank you Hogancamp! I know that there are infinitely many ways to define a set of generators for a given Lie algebra, but the number of generators in such a set is fixed and is called the dimension of the Lie algebra/group, as far as I know.. Could you elaborate a little bit more on how you have found the ninth generator? I understand the differentation part, but not the sentence before that. And how could I check this answer? I understand that in order to comment you need to edit your previous comment..

Comment: Hey I can comment now!  Right, so first, unitariness implies that for any unitary matrix $A\in U(n)$, $det(A)$ is a complex number with norm 1, say $e^{i\theta}$.  So by multiplying by the appropriate matrix of the form above (with minus $\theta$), you get an element in $SU(n)$.  Going backwards, we've shown that any unitary matrix is a product of a (unique!) element in $U(1)$, with a (unique!) element of $SU(n)$.  It follows that the Lie algebra (tangent space at 1) splits as the 1 dimensional guy $\mathfrak{u}(1)$ together with $\mathfrak{su}(n)$.

Comment: A different (better) way of saying this is that the lie algebra of $U(n)$ is the space of hermitian matrices (not traceless).  You can see this by expanding the condition $(I+\epsilon X)^\ast=(I+\epsilon X)^{-1}$ to first order in $\epsilon$).  Presumably you've seen this.  So a "ninth generator" $\lambda^9$ would be characterized by the property that $\lambda^9$ is hermitian, and NOT traceless.

Comment: I just wanted to add that there are in fact countably many $U(1)$s in $U(n)$, up to conjugacy.  And almost all (in an English sense) of these can be used to make the ninth generator.  Another natural choice would be those matrices of the form $e^{i\theta}\cdot I$, giving the ninth generator $i\cdot I$.  It's not clear to me what properties one wants the ninth generator to satisfy, so it's not clear to me which one is the "best".